# How to set company gmail account on Empathy

Tags: 12.04, email, empathy, evolution, gmail

- Hi, We are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in our company. I am given Google
  email for business with email id like sunny@mycompany.com. All of our
  staff is using empathy for internal communication as well as for
  gtalk.
- But when I try to add my email account in empathy list of accounts, it
  adds the email to list but shows  *"Disconnected - No Reason
  Specified"* below the account.

[image: Addiing Account]

- I also could not chat within our network by "People Nearby" option, I
  can see the messages sent to me, but when I try to reply them, the
  chatbox says: *Error sending message 'hi': offline*

[image: When using "People Nearby" option]

- If you guys know how to configure business class gmail account in
  empathy please let me Know.
- Also if you need more info like logs or something, then I will
  provide it.